# jpeg: reduce picture size without changing resolution and quality

Tags: compression, jpeg

I'm trying to reduce file size of a bunch of JPEG files, say 1280x720. Without changing the resolution and the visual quality much, what are the recommended approach?

Answer (score 4):

JPEG is based on DCT and entropy encoding.  If your image is not entropy-optimized yet, there might be a chance to reduce the size.

If you have a Debian or any other Linux system, try using `jpegoptim` from the same named package, or `jpegtran` from `libjpeg-progs`. The man page of `jpegtran` states that it is lossless:

> jpegtran  works  by rearranging the compressed data (DCT coefficients),
>   without ever fully decoding the image.  Therefore, its  transformations
>   are  lossless: there is no image degradation at all, which would not be
>   true if you used djpeg followed by cjpeg to accomplish the same conversion.

I also found the following two tools, which I've never tried:

- [jpeg-compressor](http://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/)
- [FILEminimizer Pictures](http://www.balesio.com/fileminimizerpictures/eng/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

If the curent image size is larger that 1280 x 720 (which is likely if these are camera images) then the best way is to reduce the number of pixels to 1280 x 720.

If they are already at 1280 x 720, then the easiest way is to reduce the JPEG quality. Most imaging software has some way of changing this, and a lower quality will reduce the file size. You'll need to check wehther the quality is still acceptable though.

Another way may be to save the file as a GIF or BMP with compression. This will only help with simple, flat-colour images though, not with photos.

I don't know what software you are using, but I can recommend [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I was more hoping for a set of tweak settings when saving as new JPEG.

Comment: GIF will effectively kill the image, as it will be reduced to 256 colors.

Comment: @Bobby correct, but if the image is suitable it will really reduce the size. Lang2 Changing the quality setting is just that, a tweak of the settings. Changing the image size requires another action before saving it.